# Autosuggest in div tag using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 10 sections name that starts and end with `[[` and `]]` respectively..

I have to do autosuggestion on div tag which is set to `contenteditable=true`
when user write `[[` then it shows section name..

Autocomplete is not supported in div tag

```
 <div id="textbox" class="mousetrap" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="true">
                        </div>
$(function() {
                var availableTags = [
                    "Window",
                    "Door and frame",
                    "Ceilling",
                    "Condition"
                ];
                $("#textbox").autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                }); 
             });
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please add your html and js code both over here?

Comment: @NeerajKumar I have done only this much

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code a bit then it will start working

Just like below

```
 $(function() {
                $.fn.val = $.fn.html;
                var availableTags = [
                    "Window",
                    "Door and frame",
                    "Ceilling",
                    "Condition"
                ];
                $("#textbox").autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                }); 
             });
```

Rest you are done.

Any ways i am putting my whole code below

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function(){
        $(function() {
                $.fn.val = $.fn.html;
                var availableTags = [
                    "Window",
                    "Door and frame",
                    "Ceilling",
                    "Condition"
                ];
                $("#textbox").autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                }); 
             });
        });
        //]]>  

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="textbox" class="mousetrap" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="true">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: shows err:Object doesn't support property or method 'prop' in jquery-ui

Comment: $("#textbox").autocomplete({}); is used..autocomplete is supported in div tag?

Comment: Where are you using prop? And yes it is supported in contenteditable true of a div in html5 that's what i have given you the complete code.